# Android java layout - Top line creating

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Probably I've got a bad day, because I'm not able to find a tutorial with Google. So I'm sorry  for asking this.

Please, do you know some good technique how to create top line? - with logo, 2-3 buttons, loader button - example: http://goo.gl/9kJMr.

I know I can do a gradient line with some height, buttons and place images as dividers. But I believe there is a better solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). You can Google a bit for it and you'll find a few implementations including (in no particular order):

- There's a [native Android implementation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) but only for SDK 11+.
- There's an implementation in [iosched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/)
- [johannilsson's implementation](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) at github.
- [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid)
- [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)
- [A new sample project](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) on the Android site that uses the native ActionBar on API 11+ and has its own implementation for pre-API 11.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) sample from google. Maybe it helps you.